# Retrofit2 Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: retrofit

I use django as server side 
In django, I return Json like this

```
return JsonResponse({'message':'Invalid login details supplied.'})
```

Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

but this error is generated

```
class Account {
    String message;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

```
public interface Login {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<List<Account>> repoContributors(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password);
}
```

```
RetrofitConnection.Login service = retrofit.create(RetrofitConnection.Login.class);

    final Call<List<RetrofitConnection.Account>> repos = service.repoContributors(string_id,string_pw);

    repos.enqueue(new Callback<List<RetrofitConnection.Account>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<RetrofitConnection.Account>> call, Response<List<RetrofitConnection.Account>> response) {
            System.out.println(response.code());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<RetrofitConnection.Account>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG",t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
```

I don't know why problem is generated

Answer (score 0):

since a `List` is expected you should return an array in JSON 
like this

```
return JsonResponse([{'message':'Invalid login details supplied.'}])
```

note thte square brackets(`[]`) in answer